# how to make increasing arrow and decreasing arrow in React for sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

i have made a table and i can sort multiple columns now what i want is that after clicking a particular button i get an increasing symbol on button and a decreasing symbol on the button if click it again below is my code for function that changes the column and also the direction and also gave the buttons as an example

```
function change(set){
      let direction='asc';
      if(sortOrder==='asc'){
        direction='desc';
      }
      setSortBy(set);
      setSortOrder(direction);
    }

<table>
<th><button onClick={()=>change('name')}>
                     Name
                    </button></th>
<th><button onClick={()=>change('total')}>
                    Total
                    </button></th>
</table>
```

so anyone can show me how can i achieve arrows

Comment: Did i get the question right? So if you sort in increasing order it should show up-arrow, else down-arrow?

Comment: yes you got it right,but it should show for the particular column which i clicked currently

Answer (score 0):

For simple table content sorting try data-table.
For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component

Comment: this will not be my use because my data output depends on user toggle it would better if i could code that arrow functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain the column sort order in state. When you click on a column/button you update the state, and the changes will be reflected in the render. Use data attributes to identify the columns/buttons. And, unless you're using a separate CSS library for anything else in your project, just use the unicode up/down arrows.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {

  // Use an object to maintain the column sort order
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({ name: 'asc', total: 'asc' });

  function handleClick({ target }) {
  
    // Instead of attaching a handler to each button,
    // there is one on the table, and we simply need to check
    // that the element we've clicked on is a button instead.
    if (target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {

      // Grab the type (name, total etc) from the data attribute
      const { dataset: { type } } = target;

      // Set the state of the new order
      setOrder(prev => {
        const newOrder = prev[type] === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        return { ...prev, [type]: newOrder };
      });

    }
  }

  // Return the arrows
  function getArrow(order) {
    if (order === 'asc') return '↑';
    return '↓';
  }

  return (
    <table onClick={handleClick}>
      <th><button data-type="name">Name {getArrow(order.name)}</button></th>
      <th><button data-type="total">Total {getArrow(order.total)}</button></th>
    </table>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: initially i wanna keep all of them in default

Comment: I don't know what that means.